# Substituição pós virgula no C#

Tags: c#

Pessoal estou usando o Visual Studio 2015 e gostaria e gostaria de substituir um texto para após a segunda virgula.
Se o ID for igual (no caso 501) ele substitui a tradução depois da 2° (e antes da 3°)

Exemplo:

Arquivo com as traduções:

```
501
Poção Vermelha
```

Arquivo a ser traduzido:

```
501,Red_Potion,Red Potion,xxx
```

Resultado final:

```
501,Red_Potion,Poção Vermelha,xxx
```

O arquivo sem virgula esta na TextBox1 e o com virgulas esta na TextBox2

Comment: O que de fato você está querendo fazer, existem outras formas mais apropriadas para você tratar idiomas e traduções. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f.aspx

Comment: @LeandroAngelo eu quero fazer usando o metodo replace

Comment: Não podes fazer como array?

Comment: É por que isso é um texto grande que estou editando. Cada linha é um elemento de uma array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De forma simples consegue fazer isso com um `Split`:

```
string[] split = textBox1.Text.Split(',');
split[2] = "Poção Vermelha";
textBox2.Text = string.Join(",", split);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
// traducoes
var traducoes = new List<String> { "501", "Poção Vermelha" };

// texto
var linha = "501,Red_Potion,Red Potion,xxx";

//divide os itens por vírgula
var itens = linha.Split(',');

//id para procurar no arquivo de tradução
var id = itens[0];

//pega o índice do id nas traduções
var indexId = traducoes.IndexOf(id);

//verifica se achou o id nas traduções e se existe uma linha após ele
if(indexId != -1 && indexId + 1 < traducoes.Count)
{
    //tradução encontrada pelo id no arquivo           
    var traducao = traducoes[indexId + 1];

    //faz a troca
    itens[2] = traducao;

    //une as partes novamente
    linha = string.Join(",", itens);
}
```